# Getting CSV values in mySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, database, csv

So I have some CSV values stored in a mySQL database.

For example:

```
ID    Name     parentID
1     Dave     1,4,6
2     Josh     2
3     Pete     10
4     Andy     2,10
```

Using this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `parentID` LIKE %4%
```

Only Dave will be returned, this is correct.
However if I select using: LIKE %1%, pete and andy are selected as well as dave, because they conatin '1'.

I need the query to be able to distinguish '10' for example, from '1'. 
It needs acknowledge each value between a comma is distinct and appreciate the fact the last comma may be omitted.

Am I right in thinking perhaps REGEX could do the job instead?

Thanks.

Comment: The only actual non jury-rigged method would be to not save CSV values in a relational database. Make a table matching ID's to parentID's

Comment: The context is that parentID value in this table, refers to the primary ID of another table.

Comment: That makes it even more clear you need a different database scheme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to match "word boundaries":

```
WHERE parentID RLIKE '[[:<:]]4[[:>:]]'
```

Or you can use a special function that parses elements of a comman-separated string:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('4', parentID) <> 0
```

---

I agree with the comment from @Nanne.

You will also find that it's better to store data not in comma-separated lists, but in a normalized fashion.  I don't know if you have freedom to change your schema at this time, but for what it's worth, read my answer for the question [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Thank you. FIND_IN_SET() was a perfect implementation

Comment: @BillyJakeO'Connor Did you want to mark this one as answered?